# Save current time and date in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to save the current time and date in my mysql database with this line of code:

```
DateTime.now
```

but when I save it in my database and then review it I get this:

```
2018-12-06 00:18:46
```

I think that the time is wrong and that affects the date.
How could I solve that?

Comment: Where are you from? I guess you have the common timezone problem. How are you "reviewing" the date value? You should usually use "I18n.l(your_date)" (that's a downcase L letter) when showing your datetimes on rails since it will localize the date to the app's TimeZone configuration.

Answer (score 1):

By default Rails always converts time to UTC before it writes or reads from the database, there is nothing wrong with that.

You can change this behavior at application init, for example, in `/config/application/rb`:

```
config.time_zone = 'Atlantic Time (Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

If you are looking for a way to store record creation/last update date, you can use timestamps, that will automatically store your record update/created at time and date.

In your migration file:

```
class CreateThings < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :things do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Otherwise, the right approach of getting the correct local time would be

```
Time.zone.now
```

You can get a full list of supported time zones with

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map(&:name)
```

[Timezone docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html), [a quick rundown](http://stevenyue.com/blogs/date-time-datetime-in-ruby-and-rails/) on date, time and time zones in Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your code? Preferably a part of model and controller that is responsible for that action.

Comment: this is my code: @assistant.date_deliver_tag_name = Time.zone.now

Comment: Did you set your timezone in your application.rb file?

Comment: config.time_zone = 'America/Mexico_City'